# CLI command "createwallet" does not work on testnet VM

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cli

I have a headless virtual machine to try out some stuff in testnet. Strangely, I can not use the `createwallet` command. It gives me the error

```
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

This is the case for all wallet-related commands. It cannot be because I'm missing Berkeley DB, can it? Because for newly created wallets I read it's not needed.

One additional point: I'm still syncing up with the testnet chain. But this shouldn't be an issue in my opinion.

Maybe I somehow did compile core without a wallet (but I don't know how to disable a wallet during installation)...

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Berkeley DB is only needed for legacy wallets (not the current wallet) but sqlite3 is needed. You have that installed?

Comment: you're right, I didn't install berkeley DB. Can I fix this without having to setup a totally new node? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I have almost 100% confidence that you compiled your core without wallet. How did you compile it? Your environment has all required decencies? Did you use a custom config flag?

Comment: I didn't use a costum config flag but I forgot installing sqlite... Dunno how to reconfigure yet though